# VSTS building all branches

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, git-branch

I'm moving CI setup from TeamCity to Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) switching to the built in Team Services Git. It all seems good but in TC I was able to set it up to automatically build all branches on check-in. This gave lots of benefits and significantly streamlined my process.

Team Services seems to insist that I have a branch filter, does anyone know how I can make turn this into a "build all branches" situation (or why I shouldn't build all check-ins on all branches!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Oops, sorry I figured it out. Basically, the drop down box to select the branch has a search function into which you can type anything. If you hit return twice it will take this as the filter. If you pass in "*" it will work.

[image: Branch specification in build triggers]

UPDATE

You only have to type in a `*` and it'll allow it with one enter. It's still on the Triggers tab.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible anymore to pass '*' as branch filter in a build definition. I tried in the "Get Source" step, am I missing something?

Comment: This is for a branch filter in the trigger. They've changed it so you don't even have to press return twice - it's just once now. You don't specify a branch when specifying the source

Comment: @Stu - can you please edit an answer and add that it is on trigger tab?

Comment: If we specify * in branch specification in triggers means, if check-in happen in any branch will trigger this build. But I hope this build will always  take source code from only one branch instead of the code check-in branch.